# Как отобразить гостевую ОС virtualbox в netwok'e хоста?

Tags: сеть, virtualbox

Есть ОС `Windows 7`. На ней установлен `Virtualbox` с ОС `Ubuntu`.

Я хочу, чтобы в ОС виртуалбокса (т.е. в убунту) можно было зайти через вкладу `сеть` хоста.

Т.е. так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ну или добавить через подключение сетевого диска

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и через сеть бегать по папкам любым.

---

На данный момент у меня получается всё наоборот. Т.е в виртуалбоксе прописаны адаптер `NAT (eth0)` и `Виртуальный адаптер хоста  (eth1)`
а в `Ubuntu` у  (eth1) прописаны

```
ip         192.168.137.1
маска      255.255.255.0
шлюз       192.168.137.1
сервер DNS 192.168.137.1
```

И из сети гостевой ОС, т.е. `Ubuntu` виден мой хост `Windows 7`:

`Сеть -> Сеть Windows -> WORKGROUP -> COMP_NAME -> ДИСКИ ВИНДЫ`

А я хочу чтоб из винды в сети был виден мой убунтик.

Пробовал в виртуалбоксе делать и `Сетевой мост` и `Внутренняя сеть` - но у винды все равно не видно в network'e ничего.

Что надо сделать? Где и что поставить и что написать? Может быть в гостевой надо какие-то команды выполнить дополнительно?

Хотелось бы прям инструкцию, типа: у `virtualbox` поставить такую-то сеть, в гостевой поставить такие-то настройки сети, выполнить такие-то команды, подправить такие-то файлы.

Весь день мучаюсь, никак.

Comment: Если вы желаете видеть в Сетевом Окружении винды свою убунту, то думаю для начала нужно поставить пакет samba (не уверен что он остановлен по умолчанию т.к. не пользователь убунту). `sudo apt-get install samba` ну и так и далее - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20Create%20a%20Network%20Share%20Via%20Samba%20Via%20CLI%20(Command-line%20interface/Linux%20Terminal)%20-%20Uncomplicated,%20Simple%20and%20Brief%20Way!

Comment: @Валерий Да. То что нужно! Поставил, прописал, всё появилось. Пол дня возился и гуглил. А тут все так просто. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно в гостевой ОС установить пакет samba (`sudo apt install samba`)
и настроить его [manual](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/samba)